# how to get pg_dump to include create user command

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a dump of all the commands below.

```
   test=> create user rdstest login password 'rdstest';
   CREATE ROLE
   test=> grant connect on database test to rdstest;
   GRANT
   test=> create user devadmin login password 'devtest';
   CREATE ROLE
   test=> grant connect on database test to devadmin;
   GRANT
   test=> grant rdstest to devadmin with admin option;
   GRANT ROLE
   test=> grant rdstest to devadmin;
   GRANT ROLE
   test=> create schema authorization rdstest;
   CREATE SCHEMA
```

when i tried to  create it using pg_dump
as pg_dump -U devadmin -h ****xxx.rds.amazonaws.com  test > Outfile.sql

I can only see the schema related commands

```
CREATE SCHEMA rdstest;
ALTER SCHEMA rdstest OWNER TO rdstest;
```

How to get pg_dump to include all the commands:create user command,grant connect on database test to rdstest etc.

Answer (score 27):

`pg_dump` can not do that, because `pg_dump` only dumps a single *database* and that information is not part of one database, but stored globally in the Postgres "cluster".

You need to use `pg_dumpall` for that, using the `--globals-only` option:

```
pg_dumpall --globals-only  --file=globals.sql
```

Comment: ... and maybe you should add: similar for table spaces, which are also installation-global.

Comment: i just want dumps of test database( user,groups etc) using --globals-only option produces dumps of global objects that are common to all databases. Is it possible to get the user,group for a particular database?

Comment: @nadish as I have already written in my answer: users/roles are **not** specific to a particular database. They **are** global